# How to create digitalocean firewall for postgresql

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I'm looking at how to create a digitalocean firewall for my docker container.

I know how to create a rule for TCP port 5432. However I still want to connect using pgadmin.

How can I only allow local connections, and two connections from the IP address of a couple of specific computers?

[image]

Comment: It depends where your pgadmin is running. If it is running on a separate container on the same host then it is a different story then when pgadmin is running on your own laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the situation (docker-compose.yml file) where you have the postgres db and pgadmin running in their own Container.

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: "no"
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - postgresql_network
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    networks:
      - postgresql_network
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "8087:80"
    volumes:
      - ./deployment/pgadmin/pgadmin4/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: me@myself.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin123
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb

networks:
  postgresql_network:
    name: postgresql_network
```

To be complete, also the servers.json file for pgadmin:

```json
{
    "Servers": {
        "1": {
            "Name": "Local",
            "Group": "Servers",
            "Host": "postgres",
            "Port": 5432,
            "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
            "Username": "root",
            "SSLMode": "prefer",
            "SSLCert": "<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.crt",
            "SSLKey": "<STORAGE_DIR>/.postgresql/postgresql.key",
            "SSLCompression": 0,
            "Timeout": 10,
            "UseSSHTunnel": 0,
            "TunnelPort": "22",
            "TunnelAuthentication": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Running this docker-compose.yml on Digital Ocean means that the following ports are necessary:
5432 for Postgres
8087 for pgadmin

### UFW

I would recommend to use the command line interface to the Digital Ocean firewall. This is UFW and it is quite easy to use.
Rules for specific IP addresses are as follows:

```sh
ufw allow from 99.99.99.99 proto tcp to any port 5432
ufw allow from 99.99.99.99 proto tcp to any port 8087
```

The first one allows access from 99.99.99.99.to port 5432, the database.
The second one from that IP to 8087, the pgadmin software.

### Local connections

The local connections between pgadmin and postgres are handled in the docker network itself. Don't worry about that, you don't need to UFW those.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer! I actually have pgadmin setup on my computer, not docker-compose. But maybe the best/most secure option would be to secure port 5432 to only local connections in docker-compose (`ports: - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432')? Then allow public connections to 8087 after setting up a pgadmin continer?

Comment: If you only allow local connections to 5432 (Database), then the pgadmin on your host cannot reach it. The DockerContainers create their own network. The Host is an outside computer and not on their localhost network. If you run the pgadmin in a sibling-container (means: on the same Docker-network), then pgadmin can reach the db via that network and no firewall needs to be set up.